# TStringGrid - is there a simple way to get the "current/selected" row?

Tags: delphi, c++builder, vcl, tstringgrid

I can go the long way round, loop over each row, get a `TRect` from `CellRect(col, row)`, then query its `State` for `gdSelected` ...

But isn't there a quicker way to get the row number of the currently selected row, if any?

Comment: Note that your variable names are unfortunate, as they hide properties of the grid. For loop variables you should probably use something like `RowIndex` and `ColIndex` to avoid the problem.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

.Row for selected row, .Col for selected column

Comment: D'oh!  How on earth did I miss that??? Thanks, both. Andre answered first, so I award him the answer and up you both. If only all questions were this easy, eh?

Answer (score 14):

Please have a look at `TStringGrid.Row`.

Answer (score 1):

With FMX, I'm using `StringGrid1.Selected`, but I changed property >> Options > RowSelect = true