# Show currently selected row in string grid

Tags: delphi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [TStringGrid - is there a simple way to get the “current/selected” row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107683/tstringgrid-is-there-a-simple-way-to-get-the-current-selected-row)

How do I show the Currently selected row as a string or a integer? I want to refer to it later if possible. This would be in a string grid of course.

Comment: @SandipArmal What are you talking about? I want to be able to highlight lets say, 1,1 and click a button then it show up in a showmessage as 1,1 or 1 1

Comment: To get string of the currently selected cell, use `StringGrid1.Cells[StringGrid1.Col, StringGrid1.Row]`.